# Missing varibale binding in Drools guided decision table

Tags: drools

I am using kie workbench's 6.2 guided decision table and I am stuck with the following scenario

I want to set the promocode in promotion only if the PromoCode from EligibilityCriteria is checked against the some values in the rule.  like shown below in code generated by workbench from the decision table

```
//from row number: 1
rule "Row 1 test"
dialect "mvel"
when
    $e : EligibilityCriteria( $code : PromoCode in ( "code1", "code2" ) , $make : vehMake == "BMW" )
then
    Promotion p = new Promotion();
    p.setPromoId("123");
    p.setPromoCode($code);
    insertLogical( p );
end
```

If no value is specified for the promocode on the text box on guided decision table the generated does not creates the variable $code and the code fails since $code is not created

```
//from row number: 1
rule "Row 1 test"
dialect "mvel"
when
    $e : EligibilityCriteria($make : vehMake == "BMW" )
then
    Promotion p = new Promotion();
    p.setPromoId("123");
    p.setPromoCode($code);
    insertLogical( p );
end
```

I just want to somehow indicate whether the rule field for promocode is empty or it has some value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no value is given in the column where the list of PromoCode values is provided you need another rule, i.e., the right hand side cannot contain the same statement sequence. Omit the selection mark for the RHS action, to avoid the generation of a statement referencing `$code` and provide an alternative action which obtains the PromoCode value by accessing the fact:

```
p.setPromoCode($e.getPromoCode());
```

Note that you may use this form of the code in any case - so you might get by with a single action column.

Comment: p.setPromoCode($e.getPromoCode());
Always gives me the value of promo code that I sent in EligibilityCriteria fact. It remains the same irrespective of whether promocode column on decision table UI has some value or not.

Comment: The rules will be created by marketing guys and they may or may not enter the promocode values. If the values are entered then the code works fine since the comma separated list of promocde on rules UI is checked against the promo code value in EligibilityCriteria fact. However when no value is provided on UI then no check is done, and whatever promocode is sent through EligibilityCriteria is consider as valid. In code I want to set promocode as valid only if it is checked against some value on UI.

Comment: Then your marketing guys will have to mark another action column, i.e., one where the code for setting the promocode as unchecked is selected, as opposed to the one you have shown in the rule which is the one for indicating that the promocode has been checked against values.

Comment: Thanks Laune. This is how I have implemented now.